# Access in a specific position of JSON in node js

Tags: javascript, json

I have a xml file which I convert to JSON for simplify some operations.

I wrote this snippet:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var parser = require('xml2json');

var fileXML = '';
var str = '';

fs.readdirSync('C:/Users/dir/').forEach(file => {
    if(file.includes('.xml')){
        fileXML = file;
    }
});


fs.readFile( 'C:/Users/dir/'+fileXML, function(err, data) {
    var json = parser.toJson(data);
 });
```

`var json` is a JSON representing this:

```
{
   "event:eventsList":{
      "xmlns:event":"info",
      "event:header":{
         "event:fileName":"info1",
         "event:creationDate":"2017-03-28T17:10:00.113+01:00",
         "event:eventsAmount":"4",
         "event:messageId":"2"
      }
   }
}
```

My question is, how I can access the `event:eventsList` property?

I tried `json.event` but it gives me error.

Comment: Please include the error you are receiving. Also, JSON is a string format, so perhaps `json` is actually a string, not an object as you (and the answerers) seem to expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access the `event:eventsList` key you need to make use of the `brackets notation` since your key is not a valid JSON key

```js
var json = {
       "event:eventsList":{
          "xmlns:event":"info",
          "event:header":{
             "event:fileName":"info1",
             "event:creationDate":"2017-03-28T17:10:00.113+01:00",
             "event:eventsAmount":"4",
             "event:messageId":"2"
          }
       }
    }
    
    console.log(json["event:eventsList"])
```

Comment: thanks for the fast answer, but it print undefined on my application

Comment: where are you tring to have this console.log in your application

Comment: i put the `console.log` right after `var json = parser.toJson(data);`

Comment: is json a string

Comment: i have to put json.parse?

Comment: yep var data = JSON.parse(json)

Answer (score 4):

Use `json["event:eventsList"]`, you can access object key this way